# Strange crash in -[UIView nextResponder]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, objective-c-runtime

The crash actually happens in `objc_getAssociatedObject(id, const void*)` which is called in the `UIView` implementation of `nextResponder`.
Here is the stacktrace :

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a43764a std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, void*>*> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<unsigned long, std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, objc_references_support::DisguisedPointerHash, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<unsigned long, std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, objc_references_support::DisguisedPointerEqual, true>, objc_references_support::ObjcAllocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*> > >::find<unsigned long>(unsigned long const&) + 57
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a437623 std::__1::__hash_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, void*>*> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<unsigned long, std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, objc_references_support::DisguisedPointerHash, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<unsigned long, std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*>, objc_references_support::DisguisedPointerEqual, true>, objc_references_support::ObjcAllocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<unsigned long, objc_references_support::ObjectAssociationMap*> > >::find<unsigned long>(unsigned long const&) + 18
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a436753 _object_get_associative_reference + 158
3  UIKit                          0x300ec2a5 -[UIView nextResponder] + 24
4  UIKit                          0x300ec279 -[UIResponder(Internal) _responderWindow] + 20
5  UIKit                          0x300ec251 -[UIView(Internal) _firstResponder] + 20
6  UIKit                          0x300ec22d -[UIResponder isFirstResponder] + 24
7  UIKit                          0x300ebc93 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:] + 662
8  UIKit                          0x300ec569 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 80
9  UIKit                          0x300ec493 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 394
10 UIKit                          0x300ec58b __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 114
11 UIKit                          0x300ec493 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 394
12 UIKit                          0x300ec58b __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 114
13 UIKit                          0x300ec493 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 394
14 UIKit                          0x30388e0b __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 378
15 UIKit                          0x300eb711 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 80
16 UIKit                          0x303bda51 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke485 + 220
17 UIKit                          0x303ba4bf -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 82
18 UIKit                          0x303bcab3 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 150
19 UIKit                          0x302003a7 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 102
20 UIKit                          0x301240f5 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 308
21 UIKit                          0x30123d0d -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
22 UIKit                          0x30123c1f -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
23 QuartzCore                     0x2fb1c2d9 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 236
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a9897a7 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a98cfa3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 718
26 CoreFoundation                 0x2cbf53b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
27 CoreFoundation                 0x2cbf3ab1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1512
28 CoreFoundation                 0x2cb413c1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
29 CoreFoundation                 0x2cb411d3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
30 GraphicsServices               0x33f3f0a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
31 UIKit                          0x3014f7b1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
32 My App                         0x000567b7 main (main.m:14)
```

This is strange because all of this seems to be happening inside the default implementation of UIKit classes, so I don't see how my code could be responsible for this.
On the other hand, the use of objective-C associated objects is usually the sign of third party code that can't use an ivar.

Also, what coud cause `objc_getAssociatedObject` to crash ? The use of a deallocated object as the first parameter maybe ?

None of my code uses `objc_getAssociatedObject` bu the way... I ran `grep -R 'objc_getAssociatedObject' .` in my project directory, all I got is a binary match for Google Analytics and Parse libraries.

This is happening on an iPhone 5c running iOS 8.1.3. The crash report comes from Crashlytics, so unfortunately I don't know where or when it happens....

Comment: What is the exception? Is there any printouts on the console about it?

Comment: We need some further detail other than your error message to be able to help you. Some code maybe?

Comment: This is a crash report I got from Crashlytics, so unfortunately I don't have much more context to provide. The crash reason is the quite usual EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c

Comment: @deadbeef Did you ever manage to fix it ?

Comment: @jbouaziz No I never did... It never happened again, so I didn't look into it too much. Also this was probably due to memory corruption caused by something else, so it's almost impossible to track.

Comment: @deadbeef I got to the same conclusion, I can't seem to find where it's coming from. Thanks for getting back at me !

Comment: I'm seeing a similar crash in my Hockey crash reports.